# Is there a VS Code shortcut to open active file in another tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-keybinding

All I've been able to find is <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd>, which opens the active file in another window. Searching for a keyboard shortcut to open the active file in a new tab in a split window.

I want to start with one tab open with index.js, and end up with two tabs, each with index.js, ideally in a split window.

Comment: If you search for `split editor` in the Gear icon/Keyboard Shortcuts editor you'll see a few options for splitting the current file (in the same group, down, orthogonal, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keybinding command IDs you are looking for are the ones that start with the prefix `workbench.action.splitEditor`. You can open your keyboard settings file with the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command, or open the keyboard shortcut editor GUI with the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` command.

To learn more about how to customize keybindings, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings.